# Any voice-supported alternative for Google Talk?

Tags: windows, chat

As you know GoogleTalk has been discontinued recently. Is there any alternative which support voice on Windows to communicate with other gmail users? Supporting video-chat is a bonus feature. 
(the Google Hangout chrome plugin is not useful for me.)

I tried Jitsi, Gajim, Pidgin, emClient, Psi and some others. These either has no voice feature or are buggy.

Comment: any specific reason a browser plugin is not useful?

Comment: @viyyer That plugin is slow to load and does not works a smooth as expected. Additionally, I use Opera and prefer not to install Chrome.